Limit of a complicated real multivariable function
How can I calculate the limit $\lim_{z \to \infty}$ of the following function
fun[u, v, w, z] = ((1/(-16*v^2 + w^2))*2*
 (-16*v^2 + w^2*Cos[Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + w*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*
   Sin[Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + (E^(I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z)*
    (-2*v^2*(16*v^2*w - w^3 + E^((3*w*z)/2)*((-16*v^2*w + w^3)*
          Cos[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*
          (-4*v^2 + w^2)*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z]))*
      (16*v^2*w - w^3 + E^((3*w*z)/2)*((-16*v^2*w + w^3)*
          Cos[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*
          (4*v^2 + 5*w^2)*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z])) + 
     (1/(16*v^2 - w^2))*(-4*v^2*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*((-4 + 8*u)*v^2 + 
          (-5 + 4*u)*w^2) + E^((3*w*z)/2)*v^2*(16*v^2 - w^2)^(3/2)*
         Cos[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + 
        w*(w*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*((-5 + 2*u)*v^2 + (-1 + u)*w^2)*Cos[
            Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + 5*E^((3*w*z)/2)*v^2*(-16*v^2 + 
            w^2)*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + (16*v^2 - w^2)*(
            (-1 + 2*u)*v^2 + (-1 + u)*w^2)*Sin[Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*
             z]))^2 + (1/(16*v^2 - w^2))*
      (-4*v^2*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*((-4 + 8*u)*v^2 + (-5 + 4*u)*w^2) + 
        E^((3*w*z)/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*(-16*v^4 - 15*v^2*w^2 + w^4)*
         Cos[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + 
        w*(w*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*((-5 + 2*u)*v^2 + (-1 + u)*w^2)*Cos[
            Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] - E^((3*w*z)/2)*(48*v^4 - 
            19*v^2*w^2 + w^4)*Sin[(1/2)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z] + 
          (16*v^2 - w^2)*((-1 + 2*u)*v^2 + (-1 + u)*w^2)*Sin[
            Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z]))^2))/
   (2*E^((3*w + I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])*z)*v^4*(-16*v^2 + w^2) + 
    16*E^(I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z)*v^2*(2*v^2 + w^2)*
     ((1 - 2*u)^2*v^2 + (-1 + u)*(-3 + 2*u)*w^2) - 
    (-1 + u)^2*w^5*(w + I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + 
    (-1 + 2*u)*v^4*w*((9 - 2*u)*w + I*(1 - 2*u)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) - 
    v^2*w^3*((11 + 2*u*(-7 + 2*u))*w + I*(1 - 6*u + 4*u^2)*
       Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + E^((3/2)*(w + I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])*z)*w*
     (I*(-1 + u)*w^4*(I*w + Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + 
      v^2*w^2*((-13 + 14*u)*w + I*(5 - 6*u)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + 
      8*v^4*((-6 + 4*u)*w + I*(1 - 2*u)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])) + 
    E^((1/2)*(3*w + I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])*z)*w*
     ((-I)*(-1 + u)*w^4*((-I)*w + Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + 
      8*v^4*((-6 + 4*u)*w + I*(-1 + 2*u)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + 
      v^2*w^2*((-13 + 14*u)*w + I*(-5 + 6*u)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])) - 
    E^(2*I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z)*w*((-1 + u)^2*w^4*
       (w - I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + (-1 + 2*u)*v^4*((-9 + 2*u)*w + 
        I*(1 - 2*u)*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]) + v^2*w^2*
       ((11 + 2*u*(-7 + 2*u))*w - I*(1 - 6*u + 4*u^2)*
         Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])))))/E^(3*w*z); 

I've tried Limit[un[u, v, w, z],z -> Infinity], but it doesn't work.

"but it doesn't work" -- It's not clear what you mean, actually. On a different note, Limit[fun[1, 1, 1, t], t -> Infinity] works. So does Limit[fun[0, 0, c, t], t -> Infinity, Assumptions -> 0 < c < 1].

The command of 14.1
Series[fun[u, v, w, z],{z,Infinity,1}]//Normal

performs the output of the size 9.8 MB. Its first two terms are (-32*v^2)/(E^(3*w*z)*(-16*v^2 + w^2)) +  (1024*E^((-3*w + I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])*z)*v^8)/ ((-16*v^2 + w^2)*(32*E^(I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z)*v^6 -  32*E^((3*w + I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])*z)*v^6 . It's more or less clear the limit under consideration is indeterminate in the general case.

Limit[fun[u, v, w, z]/.{w -> 1, v -> 2, u -> 3}, z -> Infinity] results in 0.

Limit[fun[u, v, w, z]/.{w ->- 1, v -> 2, u -> 3}, z -> Infinity] outputs Infinity.

thanks @user64494, u,v,w,z are all positive non-zero, and v>w.

My best is Table[Limit[fun[u, v, w, z][[j]], z -> Infinity,    Assumptions -> u > 0 && v > 0 && w > 0 && v > w], {j, 1, 3}] which results in {2, 0, 1/(-16 v^2 + w^2)}.  Table[Limit[fun[u, v, w, z][[j]], z -> Infinity,    Assumptions -> u > 0 && v > 0 && w > 0 && v > w], {j, 1, 4}] fails.

Perhaps Asymptotic is sufficient to determine the limit value behavior?
asy=Asymptotic[fun[u, v, w, z],z->Infinity]
Simplify[asy, Assumptions -> u > 0 && v > 0 && w > 0 && v > w]



No, it is not sufficient. Your result takes the same 9.8 MB and the first two terms are ((-8*I)*E^(I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*z)*v^2*w^2*    (16*v^2 - w^2)^(3/2) +    (64*I)*E^((3*w + I*Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2])*z)*v^4*    Sqrt[16*v^2 - w^2]*(2*v^2 + w^2) .  It should be noticed Asymptotic uses Series.

@user64494 Obviously the result of Asymptotic doesn't use Series because some parts in my result, examplary Exp[-3 w z],  aren't expanded  in powers of z! My final result is displayed in ~10lines , no need for 10MB

Your words do not correspond to reality:  ``LeafCount` of your final result equals 1139 (the executed *.nb file on demand).

Series[Exp[z] ,{ z, Infinity, 2}] (correctly) doesn't yield a power series in z.

@evannb Thanks for your correct hint!
